# Writing a book containing ordinary text, python code and mathematical formulas - what tool to use?

Tags: programming

I want to write a book containing ordinary text, python code, mathematical formulas and also pictures/plots.

In general, how would this be done in the best way? People who publish books, how / in what tool do they write in? The only thing I can think of is LaTeX?

Comment: Do you have any idea where you'd publish? Some publishers may expect a certain format.

Comment: Point your favourite search engine at terms such as *markdown*, *Pandoc*, *nbconvert*, *literate programming*.  There is a lot of prior art.

Comment: In truth LaTeX is the one. Many other softwares are just attempts at replicating what LaTeX does (oftentimes washed down and for dummies).

Comment: Try Google docs and add-ons. If I recall correctly all those things can be done there: text, code blocks, LaTeX, pictures you can just copy and paste from Spider or Jupyter.. What's the length of your book? How much time will you spend writing? Maybe it's not worth the effort finding the "best" tool but rather use what "works" for now

Answer (score 1):

Use Scribus if you plan on formatting the book for paperback and hardcover. LaTeX is best for math and I’m sure that you can make it into paperback format or hardcover format with the LaTeX site manual. Though, using LaTeX for this seems like you’re doing twice the work when you could try to put it all of Scribus for paperback editions. LaTeX is DIY with full creative control while Scribus gives you, like any other formatting platform for paperback or hardcover, limitations based on the software.